# Can I search using regex i Gerrit over the subject of the commit

Tags: gerrit

I'm using the gerrit platform for code reviews phase.

I cannot find a way to search with regex over the subject of the message.

I've tried subject:"^.*dummy.*" but it didn't work

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The matching in the "subject" search is done by a full-text search over the subject. You can't search using regular expressions.

See the "subject:'SUBJECT'" item at the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

thanks Marcelo for your response.

I found that I can use the message item and there I can also search with regex expressions.

Comment: No problem. It's better if you add this text as a comment on my answer and then delete this answer. Consider to "accept" my answer too.